# Adding to Perl arrays and hashes

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash, cgi

I'm currently working with JSON files, creating, adding, changing and removing data from them. I'm now completely lost in the array-hash levels issue.

I have a JSON file, looking like this:

```
{
  "pages": {
    "page": [
      {
        "PID": "84634572",
        "UID": "2",
        "menu_order": "65",
        "status": "1",
        "name": "Blabla",
        "blocked": "0",
        "frontpage": "1",
        "content": [
          {
            "block1": "test3",
            "block2": "test2",
            "block3": "test5",
            "block4": "test1",
            "block5": "test4"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to add more pages to the file, and have come up with the following way of building the string from where "PID" begins, before pushing it to the existing file:

```
my %rec_hash = (
    'PID'        => $PID,
    'menu_order' => '1',
    'status'     => '1',
    'name'       => $name,
    'content'    => {
        'block1' => $block1,
        'block2' => $block2,
        'block3' => $block3,
        'block4' => $block4,
        'block5' => $block5
    }
);
```

This works, in a way, but I won't get the starting brace `{` before "PID". Any help on how to build `%rec_hash` the correct way?

Comment: What module do you use to create the JSON? [JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP), [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS), [JSON::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/JSON::Tiny), [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/Cpanel::JSON::XS), something else?

Comment: You have both `page` and `content` as arrays containing a single hash. Is that correct? Similarly, you have `pages` as a hash containing a single array `page`. I would have thought that `pages` should be an array and `page` is superfluous, or are you tied to someone else's design?

Comment: How about formatting your json for humans first? http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb62c7cf

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
push @{ $data->{pages}{page} }, \%rec_hash;
```

But your `%rec_hash` has problems.

```
my %rec_hash = (
    PID        => $PID,
    UID        => $UID,              # <-- Was missing
    menu_order => '1',
    status     => '1',
    name       => $name,
    blocked    => '0',               # <-- Was missing
    frontpage  => '1',               # <-- Was missing
    content    => [                  # <-- Array was missing
        {
            'block1' => $block1,
            'block2' => $block2,
            'block3' => $block3,
            'block4' => $block4,
            'block5' => $block5,
        },
    ],
);
```

---

By the way, this appears to be a weird data structure.

- `pages` is a single-key associative array.
- Singular `page` is an array of pages.
- `content` is a single-element array.